# How can i decrease android application size?

Tags: android, size

So i need to know, how can i decrease my app size. It is 1,4 MB and it is too much for it's funcionality. So i wonder what parts of application is adding most to app size?

Comment: it's not necessary to put a link to your own application, you know. it looks like spam to me. i'd suggested an edit to remove the link EDIT: alextsc went ahead of me :D

Comment: Images? How many of those do you have in the application folders

Comment: try to convert images to 9.png format that will drastically reduce the size of app

Comment: I have pretty much images... so this is problem ??

Comment: Do I need folder xhdpi in my application ?? that is for bigger screen phones right ??

Answer (score 4):

use Window-> Run Android Lint for your project.
this will show you unusefull things (strings, drawables....) and other issues in your project.
(you can even configure which ones are warnings/errors going Preferences->Android->Lint error checking)

hope it help's!

Comment: in eclipse->Window-> Run Android Lint - probably you can't see it because you haven't done updates in a while -  I have updated already to the newest version of android and other tools : go to Eclipse->Help->Check for updates, it will be proposed a list of updates to be made and in Window->Android SDK Manager check for updates)

Answer (score 3):

Most probable causes are:

- images
- other assets
- unnecessary third party code

Answer (score 3):

Graphics are the biggest influence to file size. Try [PNGCrush](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pngcrush) a pretty good lib to reduce the file size of png files.

Comment: In my experience pngcrush has no effect whatsoever because the Android build process performs its own optimizations on PNG files.

Answer (score 2):

APK files are just ZIP files. Use a zip utility that shows you the compressed size of each entry (like `unzip -v` if you have Linux or Cygwin) to see what file or files use up most of the space. The file classes.dex contains the compiled Java code of your project, res contains your images and other resources, resources.arsc are compiled resources, such as strings.